# Use document.evaluate in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, document.evaluate

How can I use `document.evaluate` in TypeScript? It's not a method of the `Document` type, so when I try and use it TypeScript generates an error and doesn't let me compile the code.

Is there some way I can add it to the definition of `Document` or ignore the compile error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. Since interfaces in TypeScript are extensible, you can just add the required method to the Document interface, like so:

```
interface Document{
    evaluate(xpathExpression:any, 
        contextNode?:any, 
        namespaceResolver?:any, 
        resultType?:any, 
        result?:any);
}
```

Or you could cast the `document` to `any` before calling the `evaluate` method:

```
(<any>document).evaluate('...');
```

Something along those lines at any rate.